# how to browse folders in /var/www without renaming index.html?

Tags: html

i have a VM from koding website. inside /var/www folder i have created another folder called test. this folder got few files and sub-folders in it. one of these files is index.html. i cant browse into folders from Internet browser by entering www.subdomainname.koding.io/test/x but when i rename index.HTML i can browse in folders. how can i keep index.HTML without renaming and still be able to browse in sub-folders?

Answer (score 1):

If you are running **apache** in your VM, find a configuration file such as
`/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf`
with a line like:

```
DirectoryIndex index.html
```

and replace it with

```
DirectoryIndex disabled
```

Restart apache.

To apply this just to a part of your web, you can put the line
in a `.htaccess` file within the directory to apply it to.